# Jmeter Regular expression extractor content encoding

Tags: load, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

Using Jmeter, I'm trying to login to a site by capturing the context parameter and posting that value in HTTP request by post.

I have highlighted the special characters on the parameter is transformed as below. I guess due to this authentication is failing. pls help me by providing any suggestions.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/egwcu3f91jrw88u/jmeter%20problem.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5LjB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck in Post parameters table of Http Request the column:

- "Encode ?"

Show you test plan and this particular configuration of Http request

Comment: Here is the test plan https://www.dropbox.com/s/la5wg8yrkxyd205/Payment%20Login%20page.docx